# MySQL Laravel 5.4 Import database issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the latest Laravel 5.4, and running on the latest Homestead 2.0 (with MySQL 5.7.12).

This is my 1.sql file (replaced from the actual database):

```
select now();
```

I am trying to run this command:

```
DB::unprepared(file_get_content(storage_path('import/1.sql')));
```

Laravel keeps throwing this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to >your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'select now()' at line 1 (SQL: select now();)

As I notice, no matter what's in 1.sql, Laravel throws the error. When import the actual .sql file, Laravel imports it without error.

Any solutions?

Comment: What happens if you run DB::unprepared('select now();'); ?

Comment: It returns "false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue. Reported the same here: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18390